# What do web browsers send to servers to get HTML?

Tags: html, tcp, browser, web

I've always wondered, because I see that they send 404 or 500 or whatever and they send the HTML.
But what do web browsers send packet-wise to get that information(I mean details about what the TCP packet it sends)

Comment: Try Firebug or Chrome Console and see the NET tabs. It's `header`s you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic things you need to know if you don't want to read the long specs:

Computers communicate on the internet using multiple protocol *layers* (like in an onion). The top layer is called an application layer; in the case of a browser and a web server, that protocol is called HTTP. It describes headers and response codes and such.

Underneath that protocol, there's a transport protocol called TCP that ensures that the packets sent over the Internet all arrive properly, and in the correct order. Underneath that, there's a routing protocol called IP that makes sure that the packets on the internet - flowing through a bunch of intermediary computers - do get to the destination.

Each of these layers has its own specifications, packet headers, and so forth. The HTTP packet is wrapped inside a TCP packet, and all that magic is wrapped inside an IP packet.

There are several other layers involved (google "OSI model" if you want details), but this should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

- The long read: [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)
- The simple example: [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session)

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers send HTTP requests to servers to get HTTP responses which may or may not be HTML. The format for HTTP requests is documented in the [HTTP standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Answer (score 0):

Get [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

It will let you watch all the traffic between your web browser and the server.